# Map AWS API GateWay HTTPIntegration header from Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

I am using [AWS API GateWay](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) with a [HTTPIntegration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-http-integrations.html) to map requests to an external API, injecting the external API key in the mapped request headers. I know I can provide a 'Mapped from' parameter based on i.e. the request or a string to provide the API key, but can I also map the header value from AWS Secrets Manager? In the console example below I used a raw string.
[image]